# to strip ' or " while using string in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have column names in string  , now to update table in mysql in the following code :

```
cursor.execute("""update websites SET %s = %s where weblink = %s""",(key,value,x))
```

gives error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''blog' = 1 where weblink = 'http://blogspot.com/'' at line 1")
```

**key,value = 'blog',2**

**in cursor.execute key is string and sql table columns are without string , how to solve this problem**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pgrank.py", line 28, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""update websites SET %s = %s where weblink = %s""",(key,value,x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'blog\'' = 1 where weblink = 'http://blogspot.com/' at line 1')
```

Comment: The title of your question has nothing to do with your question, or the problem you are having.

Comment: I couldnt understand this problem , is it because ' or something else change as you feel like

Comment: I can't understand you.

Comment: Please provide your actual code, as well as the actual error message you are getting with its trace.

Comment: edited you may see actual stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "inherent" replacing works fine for data, but not for table names.

In `SET %s = %s`, the first `%s` gets replaced by `'blog'` while it should be `blog` or even `` `blog` ``.

You should do

```
cursor.execute("""update websites SET `%s` = %%s where weblink = %%s""" % key, (value,x))
```

because these are two distinct technologies.

Better readability would be provided by

```
cursor.execute("update websites SET `" + key + 
    "` = %s where weblink = %s", (value,x))
```

and safety is increased if you check if `key` contains the `` ` `` character.